# Correct way to changing color of Android Canvas Path

Tags: android, colors, android-canvas

I am currently working on canvas drawing module by fingerpaint

Suppose my default color of drawing pen is black.When it comes to selecting the color by HSVColor Dialog and then touching onto the screen , all previous drawn paint is changed to the current color selected instead of previous paths black , latest storke is any color having been chosen. Would you please tell me the guidelines for modifying the onDraw Canvas or ACTION_DOWN to see if the previous stroke color is not overwritten

The below is my code

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.galden.drawsth.asynctask.UploadImage;
import com.galden.drawsth.util.HSVColorPickerDialog;
import com.galden.drawsth.util.HSVColorPickerDialog.OnColorSelectedListener;
import com.galden.drawsth.util.SystemUtils;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String sign;
    LinearLayout mContent;
    signature mSignature;
    Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
    public static String tempDir;
    public int count = 1;
    public String current = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    View mView;
    File mypath;
    LinearLayout signlayout;
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;

    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        signlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mSignature = new signature(getApplicationContext(), null);
        mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mView = mContent;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if( keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
            System.out.println("BACK");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);     
        }
    }


    public class signature extends View {
        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 10f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private float mX;
        private float mY;
        private Bitmap bitmap; // drawing area for display or saving
        private Path mPath; 
        private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;    
        private Paint paint;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            initialisePen(Color.BLACK); 
        }



        private void initialisePen(int color) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(color);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH); 
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mPath = new Path();


        }



        public void save(View v) {

            if (mBitmap == null) {
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(),  mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            }



            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            try {

                v.draw(canvas);
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()  + File.separator + "CanvasTest";
                File dir = new File(path);
                if(!dir.exists()){
                    dir.mkdir();
                }

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                String name = date + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name );
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE);
                mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getName() + " is generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mypath = file;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void clear() {


            if (paths.size()>0) 
            { 
                paths.removeAll(paths);
                invalidate();
            }   
            invalidate();
        }

        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            initialisePen(color);   
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {            
            for (Path p : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
            }
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {            
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }


        private void touch_start(float x, float y) 
        {
            undonePaths.clear();
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) 
        {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
            {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }  

        private void touch_up() 
        {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);      
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);// commit the path to our offscreen  
            paths.add(mPath);
            mPath = new Path(); 
        }


        public void onClickUndo() 
        { 
            if (paths.size()>0) 
            { 
                undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
                invalidate();
            }      
            else Toast.makeText(getContext(), "nothing more to undo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }


    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putString("signCanvas", sign);
        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_clear:
            SystemUtils.toast(this, "Clear");
            mSignature.clear();
            //mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_exit:
            SystemUtils.toast(this, "Exit");
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_undo:
            SystemUtils.toast(this, "Undo");
            mSignature.onClickUndo();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_save:
            SystemUtils.toast(this, "Save");
            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(mView);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_upload:
            SystemUtils.toast(this, "Upload");
            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(mView);
            new UploadImage(MainActivity.this).execute(mypath);
            return true;        
        case R.id.action_select:
            HSVColorPickerDialog cpd = new HSVColorPickerDialog( MainActivity.this, 0xFF4488CC, new OnColorSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void colorSelected(Integer color) {
                    // Do something with the selected color
                    mSignature.colorChanged(color);                             
                }
            });
            cpd.setTitle( "Pick a color" );
            cpd.setNoColorButton( R.string.no_color );
            cpd.show();
            return true;                
            /*case R.id.action_setting:
            SystemUtils.toast(this, "Setting");
            return true;*/
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: May its clearing the old lines because of the lines `undonePaths.clear(); mPath.reset();` in your `touch_start()` method.

Comment: even deleting these line ... it does not work..